# How to enforce type safety in a generic class to ensure response type matches the expected type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a `QueryFactory` class in TypeScript that takes two generic type parameters: `TQuery` and `TResponse`. I want to enforce type safety so that the compiler throws an error when the `TResponse` type does not match the expected response type of the `TQuery` type.
Here's my code:

```
// object examples

class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
}

class Book {
  name: string;
  author: string;
}

// the classes 

interface IBaseRequest {}

class RequestBase<T> implements IRequest<T>, IBaseRequest { }

interface IRequest<TResponse> extends IBaseRequest { }  

class GetPersonByIdQuery extends RequestBase<Person> implements IRequest<Person>, IBaseRequest { }

class QueryFactory<TQuery, TResponse> { }

// the implementation

new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, Person>(); // this is allowed as expected.

new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, Book>(); // This should not be allowed by the compiler
new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, string>(); // This should not be allowed by the compiler
```

I want to ensure that the `TResponse` type passed to `QueryFactory` matches the expected response type of the `TQuery` type. For example, `GetPersonByIdQuery` should only allow Person as the response type.
Is there a way to enforce this type safety in TypeScript? How can I implement the `QueryFactory` class to achieve this?

Comment: @jcalz you're right I added them.

Comment: Also, note that it *isn't possible* to statically verify at compile time that something from outside your program (e.g. HTTP call, DB query) matches a certain schema. You can (and should) convince the compiler with appropriate runtime checks (and there are schema validator libraries that can even generate the checks for you), but don't tilt with windmills.

Comment: That is exactly what i'm looking for the only issue i have left is that when I create a new instance like this: new GetPersonByIdQuery(); it expects me to give an argument.

Comment: I see what you want i'll make a real use case example then.

Comment: @jcalz 

The issue is solved thanks to this:

<
  TCommandOrQuery extends IRequest<any>,
  TResponse extends TCommandOrQuery extends IRequest<infer T> ? T : never,
>

Your random guesses are working.

 I think you're probably curious as to why i want this. I'll explain it shortly see this image:

https://ibb.co/Db80Rx8

basically, it's a way to not need to specify what api requests i have as I am generating all the command and query classes from c# to typescript.

I wonder how you can get skilled like you, any place I can learn because this problem took me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters of `QueryFactory` like this:

```
class QueryFactory<
    Q extends IRequest<any>,
    R extends ResponseForQuery<Q>
> { }
```

where `ResponseForQuery<Q>` is a helper type defined as:

```
type ResponseForQuery<Q> =
    Q extends IRequest<infer T> ? T : never;
```

So the first type parameter `Q` is constrained to be assignable to some `IRequest<T>` for some `T`, while `R` is constrained to be `ResponseForQuery<Q>`: that is, the type `T` for which `Q` is assignable to `IRequest<T>`.

The `ResponseForQuery<Q>` type is computed via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  The type `Q extends IRequest<infer T> ? T : never` asks the compiler to try to infer an appropriate `T`.

---

Note that such an inference only makes sense if `IRequest<T>` has an appropriate **structural dependence** on the type parameter `T`. TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), so it's not enough for your type declaration to be generic; you need the *structure* of the type to depend on the generic type parameter also.

Your example `IRequest<T>` has no structural dependence on `T`, so the type `ResponseForQuery<GetPersonByIdQuery>` fails to find anything useful:

```
interface IRequest<T> extends IBaseRequest {
    // T isn't mentioned at all here
}

type X = ResponseForQuery<GetPersonByIdQuery>;
//   ^? type X = unknown
```

The compiler has no idea what `T` might have been used in `IRequest<T>` to make `GetPersonByIdQuery`.  The types  `IRequest<Person>` and `IRequest<Book>` and `IRequest<string>` are all identical to each other, and all identical to `IBaseRequest`.  Nothing distinguishes them, so you can't infer `T` from it... and so inference fails and falls back to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

And since `Person`, `Book`, and `string` are all assignable to `unknown`, the constraint in `QueryFactory` is useless:

```
new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, Person>(); // okay
new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, Book>(); // no error!
new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, string>(); // no error!
```

Oops.  See [the TS FAQ entry "Why doesn't type inference work on this interface: `interface Foo<T> { }`?"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).

---

If we add such a dependence to `IRequest<T>`, so that the compiler can actually distinguish `IRequest<Person>` from `IRequest<Book>` from `IRequest<string>`, then things start working:

```
interface IRequest<T> extends IBaseRequest {
    invariance: (x: T) => T; // I made this up at random
}

type X = ResponseForQuery<GetPersonByIdQuery>;
//   ^? type X = Person

new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, Person>(); // okay
new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, Book>(); // error
new QueryFactory<GetPersonByIdQuery, string>(); // error
```

That's what we wanted to see.

The actual dependence in your use case is undoubtedly different from the one I made up at random, but hopefully your actual code (and that of any future readers) has such a dependence appropriate to allow inference to work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcICUICOArhFmMgN4CwAUMvcnAFzJlSgDmA3LQL60CatBABtsWZPmKkwmHAB4AKgD5kwALYAHERHURwE1FJJklygDRo5eQifLU6DOMgC8yAETvaDNSABucOxwIEiuyAAUAB4sigCUrqqRPI70CAD2IGxECGBpUOHxFMj8NCWCwmJYEgAK0FgZlN4MIHB6LGycYZ7JPnAcECwgROoARtBhAEw9DP0gACbQ7WDsIBxd7sllNKLiyOhpaQDWjSnILW2sy51u3U30cERgABZ5SytrNxt8gjtVyADiEDAtSg9RA6AAnqg5gBFEhQCHICCRSDzCTGGTWeQgsGqDTaXT6MCGDGmHEZCxWbA2aRkSjFco0MAQzQofBYTQZHAAMTycOgEPkMNULjuyBhSJR+jmJNsMnkoBg4xUyAA-MhFMhBhA-NBkhVdvyEdzELkEfIxRLkaiZWhSWB5MEIRYxbhJTb0aROZkILyoEbBcLaKoHN8hDRQJBYIgUEY5aYVdbpYZrPaTj4APQZtDIdRwBbIZ7ACRETSMchQYJzNLqMWgAJBEIDCLRDXxFyqRRcZBZ5DpdR6cCFp7F5BpR6FtKsCAoEb54ecLBh2jM1nIAAaYXZ3p5fPhgsBwLqGUh0IDymSvfoAD1VYIQBAAO7i-cmnJ5A9A8ngqGw-eWb9lAKbteyOOAIVoB9nwDN8zU-I9QRPX8A0sfYjiA2IQOzaAoDySCnxfAVYI-eRD2-U8-wFSwOlWDCsKRKBcKgWggA)